# My extension has a bug

Tags: gnome, extension

I uploaded a gnome extension forked from Background Logo (now every distro installable) [Logo Widget](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/6529/logo-widget/).
But logo hiding feature which I added won't show a logo if switched the color scheme (light or dark) in overview. I want to solve this issue.
Any advice will be appriciated. Thank you.

Comment: Hi - is this actually a question regarding Ubuntu specifically? If so, more information would be required (check out https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) - if not, there may be a better location for assistance, such as GNOME-related forums.

Comment: this would be helpful https://wiki.gnome.org/GettingInTouch/Matrix